# CSS Unremovable extra white border over an outline

Tags: html, css

I am experiencing weird behavior of input when it is focused. As you can see through the images below, an extra white border appears whatever its outline-color is.

[image: Input element with extra white border]
[image: Input element with extra white border even outline-color is blue]

I tried setting `padding: 0px;` and `box-shadow: none;` too, but still I could not remove it. One thing I realized is that setting `outline-style: solid;` does the trick, but then I couldn't see rounded corner anymore.

The image below is the same input element which has completely same css rulesets:

[image: Another input element with completely-same CSS]

```css
input {
  flex: auto;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-size: 42px;
}

input:focus {
  outline-style: auto;
  outline-color: orange;
}

body {
  background-color: #383838;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use the `auto` value. Use `solid` instead

```css
input {
  flex: auto;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-size: 42px;
}

input:focus {
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: orange;
}

body {
  background-color: #383838;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

> In addition, in CSS3, outline-style accepts the value auto. The auto value permits the user agent to render a custom outline style, typically a style which is either a user interface default for the platform, or perhaps a style that is richer than can be described in detail in CSS, e.g. a rounded edge outline with semi-translucent outer pixels that appears to glow. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#outline-style)</sup>

Comment: Sucks that Chrome made this change. Auto looked way better with the rounded edges, but now it looks godawful.

Comment: @Slbox it seems that `border-radius: 4px` does the trick for the rounded edges and I can't see any difference between the two in that case. Are you seeing something different? (I missed that difference the first time around and was also getting square corners)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @TimothéeBoucher! It looks like `border-radius` does affect outline now! It didn't when I made my comment.